# Why hot-update.json files are crowding my project directory

Tags: webpack

[image]

**Why hot-update.json files are crowding my project directory**

Every time when I run webpack in development mode with this command `webpack -d --watch` and then made any changes in app.js file or any other files webpack is watching it compiles it and add **hot-update.json** files in dist directory.

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue. I am using Webpack 4.4.1 version. I was able to solve it by adding this to my webpack output config and adding the 'hot/' folder to .gitignore file.

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: setPath('src/client/public'),
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
},
```

Let me know if this helps. Couldn't find a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: This saves me. Thanks!

Comment: Such a brilliant idea

Comment: @Sophiecai thanks, can you please accept my solution as answer?

Comment: @Jefsama thanks, can you please accept my solution as answer?

Comment: @UIguy89 i think only the owner of this post could accept your answer

Comment: @AswinK This also saved me.  Was getting so irritated because of that. thanks for the solution. As a fact it's working for Webpack 5 also.